# What is the difference between "docker image build" and "docker build"?

Tags: docker, docker-image, docker-build

I am studying Docker now and it seems "docker image build" and "docker build" work in the same way.

1. Are they totally the same?
2. Is there a way to check Question 1?
3. Why are there two identical commands (if they are the same)?

Comment: They are exactly the same. `docker build` was the original command, but later on all the image manipulation commands were moved under the `docker image` subcommand. The originals were preserved for compatability.

Comment: So goes for `docker run` and `docker container run`, `docker rmi` and `docker image rm`, `docker rm` and `docker container rm`, `docker stop` and `docker container stop`...

Answer (score 3):

Just to answer the question:

As already mentioned by @larsks and @Zeitounator both commands are doing exactly the same and there is no difference. It's written down in the docker documentation that way, but you can see that [docker build](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/build/) and [docker image build](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/image_build/) have the same description and the same options to use in their docoumentations.